# How do you make a regression model from a binary labeled dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, computer-vision, regression

Suppose I have a dataset with hand images. Hand completely opened is labeled as 0 and hand completely closed (fist) are labeled as 1. I also have a bunch of unlabeled images of hands which, if properly labeled would have values between 0 and 1. Because they are not completely opened and not completely closed.

[image: hand open]
[image: hand close]

Extra info I have is the ordering between all the pairs of unlabeled images. For example, given image A and B, I can tell you which image should be predicted with higher value, but I cannot tell you what exactly is the value. The unlabeled dataset is collected by recording a video of a closing hand from completely opened to completely closed.

**What are some machine learning techniques that I can use to give the label or predict the values of hands not completely closed and not completely opened?** I expect it to be based on ordering or ranking system. If it doesn't even require the ordering label (A > B?) then that would be a very smart algorithm.

I want the values between 0 and 1. If there's a code for it that would be a plus. Thank you.